u8 doesn't "update" in println loop
I'm currently writing a game in rust and am trying to print the percent of
the completion of an operation. But my percent doesn't increase
and just jumps to 100% at the end of the loop. I'd rather expect it to gradually increase.
I tried locking stdout, flushing it, removing a line that clears the terminal and of
course googling, but nothing yielded results.
Here's the relevant part of the code, without any dependencies in my Cargo.toml:
fn main() {
  let mut i = 0u8;
  'running: loop {
    print!("{esc}c", esc = 27 as char); // clears console
    println!("i = {}", i);
    println!("{}% done...", ((i / 255) * 100) as f32);

    if i == 255 {
      break 'running;
    }

    i += 1;

    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(10));
  }
}

Thank you!
PS: This is my first question, please point out improvements for asking questions if needed

You never change i so it's never going to get to 100%.

Oh sorry, I forgot that line

Now it's the right code

Also, i / 255 is already zero, multiplying zero by 100 and converting that to a float is still zero, classic bug but all the dupes I could find where in different languages, don't we have a [rust] duplicate for it?

@user555045 why would we need a language specific one when the bug isn't related to a languages specific handling of integers?

You must change the % print like this: println!("{}% done...", ((i as f32 / 255.0) * 100.0).round());

@Kaplan, if you're going to round in the end, you're better off declaring i as i32 and using (i * 100) / 255 (rounding down) or (i * 100 + 127) / 255 if you want to round to nearest.

@Jmb The OP seems to need the i value otherwise in his program. If the change of the declaration to i32 doesn't interfere with the program, the advice is good.

@Kaplan If the change interferes with the rest of the program, then (i as i32 * 100) / 255 doesn't require changing the type of i and should be faster than converting to f32

@Jmb Gosh, I didn't saw the point. Converting to i32 is perfectly sufficient.
